# Connect to Docker Machine remotely in Docker Toolbox

Tags: selenium, docker, ssh, docker-container, docker-for-windows

Every time i run a docker command remotely (e.g docker-machine ssh default) I  always get an error saying that default is not running although I started the docker machine manually on the Windows machine. When I run "docker-machine ls" the state is set to "Timeout" but I run it on the actually windows machine and it is "Running". Im using Docker Toolbox w/ VirtalBox on Windows 10 machine with UAC disabled. I also have a Server 2012 box that shows the same results with docker toolbox. Im running the command remotely through power shell. I installed Docker Toolbox using my local account with and without elevated permissions.

I want to be able to spin up and remove docker containers from TeamCity through the command line (Teamcity on Windows).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a proxy problem?

Comment: Im currently not using a proxy @AlexanderGeorge